# Can jQuery ready() function be used twice for the same element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jQuery `ready()` function for the document element. Here are my scripts:

*1st page:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('form#haberekle').ajaxForm(options);
});
```

*2nd page:*

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        success:showResponse,
        beforeSubmit:showRequest,
        resetForm:true
    };
    $('#haberresmiekleform').ajaxForm(options); 
});
```

These two pages are included in the same main page with `<!--#include file=""-->`

Can these two functions work properly, or they block each other?
According to my experience they seem work properly.

For example: an `onclick` function of a button is only one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can have as many [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) calls as you want, jQuery is designed with this in mind and it's absolutely ok.

So yes, it is *ok*, and you *won't* have any problems...this happens all the time.

Think of it as an event handler, like [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), this is exactly how it behaves (well, strictly speaking, not *exactly*, but for most purposes like this).  So you can have as many as you want.

One more note that may be of interest, the handlers you pass into `.ready()` [are pushed](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L260) via [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) to the [`readyList`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L62), which means they'll execute in the order you called them in the page.  The same order behavior is true (though via an array, a different method) in earlier versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is fine. Both will be called when the dom is fully loaded. Note that if you call `.ready()` *after* the dom is already loaded, the callback will be executed immediately. See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

Take a look here: 
http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready

Answer (score 1):

No problem attaching several handlers for the same event. The documentation for `ready` says :

> There is also
>   $(document).bind("ready", handler).
>   This behaves similarly to the ready
>   method but with one exception: If the
>   ready event has already fired and you
>   try to .bind("ready") the bound
>   handler will not be executed.

And the documentation for `bind` says:

> When an event reaches an element, all
>   handlers bound to that event type for
>   the element are fired. If there are
>   multiple handlers registered, they
>   will always execute in the order in
>   which they were bound

Comment: Actually `.ready()` isn't a shortcut for `.bind()`, you can see the source here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L255 It does behave in a similar way, though.